# Using SimpleMembership with multiple applications and OAuthWebSecurity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

We are looking to move our application to using the new SimpleMembership included in ASP.NET MVC 4 but we currently have multiple applications using the AspNet_Applications table of the old membership provider.

The reasons we are looking to move are the obvious ones, SimpleMembership is much smaller and we can map directly to our user table and also we want to start using OAuthWebSecurity.

Is there anyway to introduce this support by either extending SimpleMembershipProvider or even ExtendedMembershipProvider to allow multiple applications in the same database.

Alternatively should we just write our own membership which we can then use OAuthWebSecurity with without it using the webpages_ tables?

Answer (score 0):

Would prefixing the username with an application name work?

Instead of `user@example.com` you would have `5|user@example.com` or whatever format you chose. As long as you do this every time you read or write to the SimpleMembership table you'd be fine.

Create your own little abstration wrapper and I think you should be good to go. If you find any issues would be interested to hear them since I'm considering doing this myself too.